# Measuring, using and analyzing skin resistance in kohms

Tags: electrophysiology, skin, stress

What are ballpark ranges of skin resistance in Kohms for average men and their significance (for example 500-1000s = stressed vs 1000+ = fairly relaxed)

What do various skin resistances in kohms say about a person's emotional or arousal state:

For example:
Is a skin resistance of less than 0 possible and what what does that say about the person

Comment: This fact depends on the moisture of the skin, for example. You could narrow your question further. Then, having emotional/arousal state is also dependent on the moisture. Your last question: possible in some conditions; last part of the question is subjective so I do not answer it. Your first question about classifications: subjective because too wide question; you need to narrow your topic.